# Java: compile on Windows, run on OS X = fail, why?

Tags: java

I don't know much about compiling files: when I tried compiling files on Windows Vista, the JAR file works fine, the application runs just fine. I copied all files to a Mac OS X, tried to run the JAR file, nothing happen, the application doesn't work, why?

**EDIT:**
When I try to display a JFrame, I get the error only in Mac OS X:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/swing/GroupLayout$Group
```

GroupLayout is created by Netbeans by drag-and-drop components to the JFrame. Please help!

Comment: maybe different java version?

Comment: I'm sure *something* happens. What happens if you try to run it from a command line?

Comment: Show us error message that you get when execute it from your terminal

Comment: Did you run the jar with java -jar jarname ? or did clicking on it in windows just work?

Comment: Not enough information. What is the JRE version installed on Vista? What is the OS X version? When "nothing happen" are you running a java command line from Terminal on OS X? Be explicit.

Answer (score 3):

A common problem (if you have a Swing GUI), is that not all of Swing is available on OSX. I encountered this problem after creating a game in Java at university and tried to show it off to my Dad on his Mac...

Have you tried running the JAR from the command line to see what, if any exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: I got a swing exception error in Mac OS X, can you plz help me, I edited my question

Comment: @evilReiko Sorry, but the question has been closed. Try asking a new one with details on the version of java you are running on the Mac and the exception that is being thrown. Leave a link to the new question as a comment here so I can easily find it.

Answer (score 1):

If your program contains absolutely path, like

```
D:\Foo\bar...
```

it will not work.

or if it has some platform dependences code.

Try to remove this code.